# Jsoup Android parsing

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am parsing a web page ... and now when I am done... I see I am doing something incredibly stupid, so if anyone can point that out to me please :) and what would be the right direction.

I have a Android app that uses Jsoup and it works great, but it is terribly slow! I know the reason why... because basically onCreate I have 20,30 Jsoup getElement requests...

```
 private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String linkText;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Initdata();

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {

        mProgressBarHandler.hide();           

        redraw();
        inflatedView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressBarHandler.show();
    }
}
```

In the Initdata() method I have that 20-30 Jsoup requests. Even with AsyncTask it is very slow, the only diference now is that I am not blocking the UI thread,... and that is great but I need to "optimize" somehow the parsing of this elements.

```
private void Initdata(){

    loadImages();
    players = new String[] {util.GetElement("div.item-2:first-child", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(3)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(4)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(5)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(6)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(7)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(8)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(9)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0),
            util.GetElement("div.item-2:nth-child(10)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0)
    };
 vestiDescription1 = util.GetElement("div.item-big h2", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0) + System.getProperty("line.separator")
            + util.GetElement("div.item-big h3","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0);

    vestiDescription2 = util.GetElement("div.grid-8 h2 a", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0) + System.getProperty("line.separator")
            + util.GetElement2("div.grid-8 h3","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0);

    vestiDescription3 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);

    vestiDescription4 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);

    vestiDescription5 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);

    vestiDescription6 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > h2:nth-child(4)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0) + System.getProperty("line.separator")
            + util.GetElement2("div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(5)","http://www.istinomer.rs/",0);

    vestiDescription7 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);

    vestiDescription8 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);

    vestiDescription9 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);

    vestiDescription10 = util.GetElement(
            "div.gd-container-1:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(2)", "http://www.istinomer.rs/", 0);
currency = new String[]{
            vestiDescription1,
            vestiDescription2,
            vestiDescription3,
            vestiDescription4,
            vestiDescription5,
            vestiDescription6,
            vestiDescription7,
            vestiDescription8,
            vestiDescription9,
            vestiDescription10
    };

public String GetElement(String Element, String site, int mode) {
    try {

        Elements newsHeadlines = null;

        if (mode == 0) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(site).timeout(600000).get();
            newsHeadlines = doc.select(Element);
        }
        //1 gets link from class
        else if (mode == 1) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(site).timeout(600000).get();
            String link = doc.select(Element).toString();
            return link;
        }

        //Log.d("TMS", "Data is " + html2text(newsHeadlines.toString()));

        String returnData = html2text(newsHeadlines.toString());
        return returnData;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TMS", "EXCEPTION GetElement: " + Element);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error";
    }
```

Any idea how can I speed up?

Comment: For starters, post your code that actually works with jsoup. Also you'll want to provide some example HTML doc that it works with.  Here, you're just showing a basic AsyncTask.

Comment: @DougStevenson Please check the updated question. The web page is www.istinomer.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're requesting the same document to parse repeatedly on each call to GetElement!  Of course it's slow!

Instead, make ONE call to JSoup to fetch the document, then use the Document object it returns for all the queries against that document.

Comment: you mean something like public Document GetElement(String Element, String site, int mode) {
          Elements newsHeadlines = null;        
        if (mode == 1) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(site).timeout(600000).get();            
            return doc;
        } And do the quesries against this Document object I get back from this function ?

Comment: Every time you execute `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(site).timeout(600000).get();` it is fetching the page every time.  There is no cache.  You should just do it once and store the Document for all the queries on that site.

Comment: I think I understand. I`l try a quick test now.

Comment: Yep, I knew I was doing something stupid, just coulnd`t figure out what. This is about 4x faster now. Can I do anything more to optimize the speed ?